# Equivalence of two norms proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $g_n(x)=\sqrt{n}$ if $0\leq x \leq\frac{1}{n}$ and $g_n(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ if $\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq1$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|{g_{n}}\|_2=\infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|{g_{n}}\|_1=2$. Proof that this norms aren't equivalent. The two norms are equivalent if there exist $C_1$, $C_2$ such that $C_1\|{g_{n}}\|_1\leq\|{g_{n}}\|_2\leq C_2\|{g_{n}}\|_1$ for all $g_n$ in $V$. How can I prove this? If I look at the limits it's very clear because then we have $C_1*2\leq \infty \leq C_2*2$ and this isn't true for any $C_1,C_2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Something is off here. Norm equivalence usually refers to two *different* norms. Otherwise, yes infinity is not bounded by any finite number.

Comment: So it's permitted to look at the limits of those norms (instead of the norms self)@AlexR.

Comment: Working with the limits is a bit awkward, since one of the limits is $\infty$. Not a deep problem, but you can circumvent it by stating that $C_2\lVert g_n\rVert_1$ is bounded, while $\lVert g_n\rVert_2$ isn't, or by dividing by $\lVert g_n\rVert_2$.

Comment: Perhaps you should state on what space you consider these norms. And maybe ([tag:functional-analysis]) and ([tag:normed-spaces]) would be good tags for this question, too.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Fischer suggested, it is better to avoid writing things like $\le \infty\le $ when learning real analysis. The definition of equivalence of two norms amounts to the statement that their *ratio* $\|x\|_1/\|x\|_2$ is bounded between two positive constants $C_1,C_2$ (for every nonzero element $x$): 
$$C_1\le \frac{\|x\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\le C_2,\quad x\ne 0 \tag{1}$$ 
However, a computation shows that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\|g_n\|_1}{\|g_n\|_2}=0$$
Therefore, the left side of (1) does not hold for any positive $C_1$.